# setting default value to f.select not working as required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form with a drop down like this and I am setting default value for it.

```
= simple_form_for :"#{filter.underscore_field_name}",:url=> admin_requests_path,:method => "get",html: {:"data-filter"=>"#{filter.underscore_field_name}"}  do |f|
    = f.select("#{filter.name}", options_for_select(filter.filter_values.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },default_filter_value_id_det(request,filter)),{:include_blank => "None specified"},{class: "form-control chosen-select select_tag_filter",data: {"field_name"=>"#{filter.underscore_field_name}"}})
```

I am using a helper to find the default value.

```
def default_filter_value_id_det(request,filter)
    af = request.filter_value_requests.find_by(admin_filter: filter)
    if af
        af.admin_filter_value.id
    else 
        nil
    end
end
```

It is selecting the correct value when `af` is present but when the condition is `nil` it is still setting the dropdown to first value and not the correct value. Why is this?

Comment: try "" rather than nil because u need to specify string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this

def default_filter_value_id_det(request,filter)
af = request.filter_value_requests.find_by(admin_filter: filter)
if af
    af.admin_filter_value.id
else 
    ""
end
end
```

or simply

```
  def default_filter_value_id_det(request,filter)
      af = request.filter_value_requests.find_by(admin_filter: filter)
      af.nil? ? '' :  af.admin_filter_value.id
  end
```

Comment: I reloaded insteaded of refreshing the page. It is properly working. What the? :O